# Codeigniter Email - `554 SMTP synchronisation error

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp, html-email

I'm trying to send email using codeIgniter's email library.

Below is my code

```
$config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'smtp.myserver.com',
        'smtp_user' => 'xxx@myserver.com',
        'smtp_pass' => '********',
        'mailtype' => 'html',
        'wordwrap' => false,
        'charset' => 'utf-8'
    );
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from('xxx@yourserver.com', 'xxx');
    $this->email->subject('blah blah');
    $this->email->message('a simple html message');
    $this->email->to('any@validemail.com');
    $this->email->send();
```

Code is on diffrent server & it is using different server's mail (Yes, two different domains)

For example code is on **yourserver.com** and it is using **smtp of myserver.com**

It was working fine till morning. but now i'm getting

`554 SMTP synchronisation error` (see attachment for full print_debugger() output, I hide some sensitive information. i can trust you guys but not all)

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried very hard to get the issue, but i have not enough access to get details of error log or mail logs, So i changed my code as below and it worked

```
$config = Array(
        'mailtype' => 'html',
        'wordwrap' => false,
        'charset' => 'utf-8'
    );
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from('xxx@yourserver.com', 'xxx');
    $this->email->subject('blah blah');
    $this->email->message('a simple html message');
    $this->email->to('any@validemail.com');
    $this->email->send();
```

I would like to say thanks to @cherrysoft for his help offering. I'm posting it here so it may help someone.

thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a CodeIgniter problem and there could be quite a few things going on here but the first thing I would do is to make sure that the hostname on the web server is set correctly and that your mail server recognises this host.  You should tail the mail.log on your mail server (if you have access to do this) whilst you are sending mail from your web server and you will get some more insight as to what is going on.  When you have the mail log entries post here and we can look at the issue in more depth.

Comment: I'll try to get mail log entries. I dont have access to server.